# Is it possible to share wolves with other players on multiplayer servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have successfully tamed 4 wolves but of course my friends aren't able to "use" them. Is there any way to transfer ownership to other players?

I asked a friend of mine to feed two of them so that at least the baby wolf could be used by him, but even doing this the newborn is only usable by me

Comment: I find sharing wolves to be a pain.  Once, me and a friend each had 3-4 wolves. During big fights with mobs, we would accidentally attack one of the other's dogs, causing them to kill us...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that once they have their leashes on them, they cannot be re-tamed, so you're going to have to find a new wolf with your friends, and make sure that they have the bones instead

Comment: yeah, that makes sense in the end I guess. But it's a pity the baby wolf trick doesn't work :(

Comment: Don't worry bud, though wolves can be a bit of a pain to find, it should all be worth it in the end for your friends :3

Answer (score 8):

This method I have found to work, but you have to have sufficient permission on the server to access the *entitydata* command.

Stand near the wolf you'd like to transfer, (it is helpful to have him sitting), and type the following command:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Wolf,r=5] {OwnerUUID:yourFriend'sUUID}
```

And voila! In order to find your friend's UUID, http://mcuuid.net/ is a helpful website.

Comment: This worked for one of my friend's wolves, but she had quite a few. I figured the `r=5` was a radius. So I set it to 500 the second time, hoping to update all the nearby wolves. Instead, there was an explosion of like 50 wolves that spawned. Keep that in mind, not sure what the deal is there. lol.

Comment: ah, you tamed em all, then they teleported to you :P

Comment: No longer works as of 1.13 as this command has been merged into `/data`

Comment: Trying to do this in 1.13+, so far I got `/data get entity @e[type=minecraft:wolf,distance=..5,limit=1] OwnerUUID 68ee64aa-5678-46a9-9e51-8733d1b1a43f` but it does not accept a UUID in the `get` command, but somehow I don't have the `modify set` command available to me... strange

Answer (score 4):

If you and your friend both have a wolf, whoever's is put into love mode first, that will be the owner I the baby, so this is an effecient way to make a large wolf pack.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this. I'll put it in steps for you.

**Materials**:

- Wolf
- Name tag
- Anvil
- Bone(s)
- Rotten flesh
- Any kind of cooked meat (No FISH)
- Dyes (whatever color)

**Procedure**:

1. Make a wolf that loves you. (Must be NAMED.)
2. Make your wolf sit.
3. Make your friend  come to the wolf and give it rotten flesh.
4. Make your friend give the wolf a different color collar with dyes.
5. Make your friend give the wolf some cooked meat. (No FISH.)
6. Both you and your friend have to log out at the SAME time.
7. Re-join and your friend should have ownership.

This is a 1.8.1 glitch. I am not sure if it will be here for the future updates. I discovered this on my own and have tested it multiple times. Basically you are tricking the game into thinking your friend is the owner, by feeding it and changing it's color. When you log-off the game reloads and your wolf is now coded to love whoever cared for it last.

Comment: I am 98% sure this doesn't work, or at least works for a different reason than the one given. *A wolf does not know who last fed it*, there simply is [no data entry for that](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk_format#Entity_format).

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that cats if one is standing while breeding with a sitting cat then the one standing becomes the main parent. So if to share a pet have your dog sitting and have the other players dog standing when breeding that should make it so it will be theirs. (probably won't be able to make it love you though).

Answer (score -4):

Use the command:

> /GivePet <player>

And then right click the pet you would like to transfer.

Comment: That is not a vanilla Minecraft command. It looks like it's from [Grief Prevention](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/grief-prevention/) which is a bukkit plugin.